# Can "Block" Message send multiple blocks?

Tags: block, network, p2p

Can multiple blocks be sent in a single block message in response to the GetBlocks message, or will a new Block message have to be sent for every block?
Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

It sends exactly one block. If you want to send multiple blocks, you need multiple messages.